# Android layout design looks different on phone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

[image: ...]

Above is a picture of the app in the design preview using a Pixel 2 XL.

[image]

Above is a picture of the app running on a Pixel 2 XL.

The Seekbar and the go button are missing. I can't figure out why it won't show when its running on the phone.

The code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TimerController">
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timerSeekBar2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerSeekBar2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/egg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        android:text="0:30"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/controllerButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Go!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share your image of egg, because i am using the same code on my machine and i checked it on Pixel 2 XL and it is looking perfect.

Comment: Try creating sub folder called `layout-sw480dp` inside  `layout` folder and your above xml file  inside it.

Comment: rajshree here is the egg picture http://oi66.tinypic.com/5zr7d3.jpg

Comment: moving it didn't seem to work either

Comment: Ok i check that.

Comment: @RaeesSharif-Aamir see this screenshot :- https://ibb.co/i4fBr8

Comment: What version of Android is your emulator using?

Comment: @RaeesSharif-Aamir API-28

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176904/discussion-between-rajshree-tiwari-and-raees-sharif-aamir).